# "She hopes to earn her living as a ___ in an office"

Tags: word-choice

I am rattled today when I tried to answer the following question:

> "Now that she is fully trained, she hopes to earn her living as a ................. in an office."
>
> Select one:
>   A. typewriter
>   B. secretary
>   C. staff
>   D. personnel

I think all of the above are correct. Can anyone help me? Please tell which one is correct and WHY other options would be incorrect.

Comment: Nope. A typewriter is an inanimate object, not a person. Both *personnel* and *staff* are mass nouns and so disqualified by the use of the indefinite article *a* (moreover, they both mean "generic employee", and so the requirement to become "fully trained" in order to work as staff/personnel would be logically incongruous anyway). The only possible answer is B, *secretary*.

Comment: Typewriters are not only inanimate, but the last of them disappeared about 20 years ago!

Comment: But maybe it's a talking typewriter from a Disney cartoon?

Comment: Had it said "computer" instead of "typewriter" we'd have needed a date

Comment: I do know someone who, when they were very young, said that she wanted to be a typewriter when she grew up.

Comment: @WS2. Your comment reminds me of an article by the BBC a year ago saying German authorities were thinking of using typewriters for sensitive documents to prevent digital spying. So maybe training to become a typist is a good career move! http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-28343371

Comment: @dumbledad - Right!  Up until about 1955 a "computer" was a person.

Comment: (But it should also be noted that what served the function of a typewriter was called a "scrivener" until the late 1800s.)

Comment: @DanBron A typewriter used to be also the person who typed using a typewriter. Now you call them a typist. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/typewriter

Comment: @user1598390 And a *computer* used to be a person who performed computations (calculations). And when *girl* first entered the English language it used to mean *child of either gender*. These words don't mean these things any more, though. Times change. A typewriter is an object now.

Comment: http://img.weburbanist.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/largescale.jpg - I beg to differ. #1 is clearly the correct answer

Comment: @DoubleDouble - I never joke.

Comment: @DanBron "Staff" isn't necessarily a mass noun; it can *also* be an inanimate object.

Comment: Should this be better asked in the English Language and Learners?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

1. A *typewriter* is a machine (now obsolete). A person who uses a
   typewriter is called a **typist**. `INCORRECT`
2. A *secretary* is an office assistant, one of whose duties is to write
   up memos and correspondence (these days usually on a computer). **`CORRECT`**
3. *Staff* is a group noun (non-count) referring to a group of people. One person can be a member of *the staff*, but she cannot be "a"
   staff. `INCORRECT`
4. *Personnel* is a group noun (non-count) referring to a group of people. One person can be part of a company's personnel, but she
   cannot be "a" personnel! `INCORRECT`

Comment: Good answer.   Staff has other potential meanings, depending on context - which would still be incorrect answers for this question.  For example "a stick or pole used to aid walking or climbing, that may be used as a weapon".

Comment: To be fair, I have seen _typewriter_ refer to a person who uses a typewriter, though not in some time. Note the archaic example on [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/typewriter).

Comment: @Etheur - I've also seen it that way once or twice.  It's similar to how a "computer" used to be a "person who computes things" rather than a machine.

Comment: And a secretary can also be a type of furniture (a desk). And a staff can be a rod/wand/stick.

Comment: I'd add that some people think *secretary* is somewhat archaic and not politically correct anymore. They prefer the term "administrative assistant".

Comment: 3. You could be a "staffer" (short for staff member) in an office.  google says this usage is North American.  But yes, "staff" doesn't fit because it's the wrong kind of word.

Comment: You can also just be a "staff member", though that sounds pretty office-speak-y, the sort of thing you'd see in a memo about utilizing resources to increase productivity. (Also, oddly, I always thought "staffer" sounded kinda British, personally.) In any case, "staff", as well as being a group noun, is also entirely nonspecific - a staff member's job could be almost anything less important than a CEO.

Comment: @MattBurland  But Secretary is also a 'position' e.g. a Club or a Company will have an official Secretary. In large companies this will most certainly NOT be an admin assistant!

Comment: @MikeBrockington - Yes, but _A secretary is an office assistant..._ in this context it's pretty clear which meaning of "secretary" is being referred to.