# Number of personnel

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is it common and acceptable to count personnel?

For e.g.

1. Five personnel will be chosen to join the contest.
2. Five Microloft personnel will be given a bonus.
3. I spoke to 3 Microloft personnel regarding the issue.

Comment: Some relevant q&a:  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62507/she-hopes-to-earn-her-living-as-a-in-an-office https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5922/when-and-why-do-does-staff-as-a-collective-noun-get-plural-singular-pronoun-ve https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3497/can-uncountable-nouns-be-counted/3502#3502

Answer (score 1):

Even though the noun "personnel" is used this way, it is a *non-countable* noun, which means that it **cannot be used** in a sentence as a plural noun. This is because the noun "personnel" is referring to all the workers as a group, and you cannot have a plural "all".

Comment: *you cannot have a plural "all"* <-- Where do you get this rule from?

Comment: I was referring to the fixed plural noun rule, my apologies. @MarcInManhattan

Comment: No need to apologize! I was just wondering because "all" can be used in the plural. (E.g.: "I have five dogs. All are German shepherds.") What is the "fixed plural noun rule"? Is it from a grammar book?